# Eclipse Kepler - Google Plugin Eclipse BUG

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-kepler

The Google plugin for Eclipse adds a button, GDT pulldown, to the Eclipse toolbar. I do not know what I did, but this button appears **seven** times, and it seems to be a bug!

Moreover, could you tell me, what should I do to not always have to sign in when I need to deploy a new GAE version (it always ask me for my Google mail and password) ?

Comment: I recommend splitting off you GAE inquiry as a separate question

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling the buttons and then re-enabling the button? Go to Window -> Customize  Perspective to do this.

[image: Customize Perspective]